# How many weekly deliveries per receiver using excel

Tags: excel, statistics

My Excel sheet is pretty simple: Column A lists all the delivery receivers and column B lists delivery dates:

```
Receiver A  20.1.2018
Receiver A  30.3.2018
Receiver A  31.3.2018
Receiver A  1.6.2018
Receiver A  2.6.2018
Receiver A  20.6.2018
Receiver A  5.7.2018
Receiver A  4.8.2018
Receiver B  2.1.2018
Receiver B  3.1.2018
Receiver B  3.1.2018
Receiver C  4.4.2018
Receiver D  2.2.2018
Receiver D  4.5.2018
Receiver D  5.5.2018
Receiver D  6.5.2018
Receiver D  5.7.2018
```

Excel itself has around 200k lines.

I would need to know following facts:

1. How many receivers gets only one delivery per week over calendar year
2. How many receivers gets 2 deliveries per week over calendar year
3. How many receivers get 3 or more deliveries per week over calendar year

I'm interested in both cases: max deliveries per receiver in any week, or average weekly amount per receiver.

Also a "shorted" table with each receiver presented only once followed by max/average deliveries per week would be very good.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a Pivot Table, it would do the trick. For the weekly stuff I'd add a third columnd with the formula WeekNum where it will return the week number of the date (of the whole year).

With that done you can insert a pivot table and use the reciever as rows, weeknum as columns and dates as count values.